# drawback of compiling for an old version of Mac OSX

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

I am maintaining an application for Mac OSX. Currently I use `-mmin-macosx-version=10.6`, but there is a very small number of users who still run 10.5. I am wondering if it's worth compiling one version for all, setting the minimum requirement to 10.5, or build twice: is there any global, non application specific drawback of enforcing compatibility to 10.5? I'm mostly concerned about performance and compatibility with modern systems, 10.7+. I'm only providing Intel x86_64 builds.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment target should have absolutely no impact on application performance. There is no reason for you to provide separate binaries.